# How to capture key-press events when using QWebEngineView?

Tags: python, python-3.x, events, pyqt5, keypress

```py
## minimal code
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtWebEngineWidgets import QWebEngineView
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt

class Browser(QWebEngineView):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Browser, self).__init__(parent)
        self.setHtml(r"""
        <div><textarea></textarea></div>
        <style>
        *{margin:0;}
        div {
            height: 100%;
            position: relative;
            background:grey;
        }
        textarea {
            background:red;
            height: 50%;
            width: 50%;
            resize: none;
            position: absolute;
            top: 50%;
            left: 50%;
            transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
        }
        </style>
        """)

class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        central=QtWidgets.QWidget(self)
        self.setCentralWidget(central)
        layout = QtWidgets.QGridLayout(central)
        self.browser = Browser(central)
        layout.addWidget(self.browser)
        another=QtWidgets.QWidget(central)
        layout.addWidget(another)
        another.setFocusPolicy(Qt.StrongFocus)

    def keyPressEvent(self, e):
        print("KEY PRESSED")
        return super().keyPressEvent(e)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = MainWindow()
    window.setGeometry(300, 50, 800, 600)
    window.show()

    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

### Current behavior:

#### Case 1:

1. Click on the white area(a widget).
2. Press a key.
3. `KEY PRESSED` is logged into the console.

#### Case 2:

1. Click on the grey area(the webview).
2. Press a key.
3. `KEY PRESSED` is logged into the console.

#### Case 3:

1. Click on the red area(the textarea inside the webview).
2. Press a key.
3. Nothing is logged into the console.

### Required behavior

I want all of the cases to log `KEY PRESSED` once into the console.

### Things I tried

I tried adding an `eventFilter` to the `MainWindow` but it gives the same outout.

I also tried the solution from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57012924/14908508) by forwarding the key events to `MainWindow` but then it logs `KEY PRESSED` twice for Case 2.

I am not able to differentiate between the events that was propagated to `MainWindow` (Case 2) and those that weren't (Case 3) so that I could've implemented something to ignore the excess function call.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that Qt must pass the events to the internal Chrome browser, which complicates the normal process of event-propagation. The simplest solution I could find is to install an event-filter on the internal web-view delegate, whilst also ignoring any events that come from the delegate in the main key-press handler:

```
class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        ...
        self.browser.focusProxy().installEventFilter(self)

    def eventFilter(self, source, event):
        if (event.type() == QEvent.KeyPress and
            source.parentWidget() is self.browser):
            self.handleKeyPress(event)
            return False
        return super().eventFilter(source, event)

    def keyPressEvent(self, event):
        target = QtWidgets.QApplication.focusWidget()
        if target.parentWidget() is not self.browser:
            self.handleKeyPress(event)
        super().keyPressEvent(event)

    def handleKeyPress(self, event):
        print(f'KEY PRESSED: {event.text()!r}\n')
```

Comment: Thanks for this answer!! I used some of the ideas from this answer along with another post to find a solution that works with lesser changes in the old code.

Comment: @JakeKorman I have updated my answer with an even simpler solution. This should require minimal changes, since all you need to do is factor out a section of the code from your current keypress handler into a separate method.

Answer (score 0):

What I did was forward the key events from the `browser` to the `MainWindow` using the `ForwardKeyEvent` class from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57012924/14908508). I ignored any `QKeyEvent` sent by the `browser` and accepted the ones that were sent artificially. This was more convenient for me since all the logging was done by one function, which is the function I needed to be called when there was a `QKeyEvent`.

```py
class ForwardKeyEvent(QObject):
    ## https://stackoverflow.com/a/57012924/14908508
    def __init__(self, sender, receiver, parent=None):
        super(ForwardKeyEvent, self).__init__(parent)
        self.m_sender = sender
        self.m_receiver = receiver
        self.m_sender.installEventFilter(self)

    def eventFilter(self, obj, event):
        if self.m_sender is obj and event.type() == QEvent.KeyPress:
            new_event = QKeyEvent(
                QEvent.KeyPress,
                event.key(),
                event.modifiers(),
                event.text(),
            )
            new_event.artificial = True
            QCoreApplication.postEvent(self.m_receiver, new_event)
        return super().eventFilter(obj, event)

class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        ...
        
        self.FKE = ForwardKeyEvent(self.browser.focusProxy(), self)
    
    def keyPressEvent(self, e):
        target = QtWidgets.QApplication.focusWidget()
        if target.parentWidget() is not self.browser or hasattr(e,"artificial"):
            print("KEY PRESSED:", target)
        return super().keyPressEvent(e)
```